# Angular 4 Material UI Google Places Autocomplete

Tags: angular, google-places-api, material-ui

I am trying to get Google Places (autocomplete field) integrated with my Angular 4/5 app which is styled with **Material UI**.

There is one module which I found [here](https://tanoy009.github.io/ng4-geoautocomplete/) but it's not exactly what I want because i can't style the input box with material design.

Is there any alternative way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: just style the original field to look similar to material input? besides the package shared is completly editable, you just cant put the mat-input tag on it, you need to manually style it.

Comment: @DanielNetzer Thanks, I can style it but just have two issues to address: 

1) Modify the input with a floating label and 2) How do i store the inputs' value? Normally I do [(ngModel)]="user.location" or something similar, BUT if I change the ngModel on this input in the package then it throws an error

Comment: and the other one? btw a floating label is something you can make with CSS aswell.

Comment: @DanielNetzer yep, css floating label won't be an issue.. mainly it's the ngModel issue now. Edited the comment above

Comment: don`t use ngModel then, use event handlers to get the value every time it changes, (change)="saveNewValue($event)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-google-place-autocomplete

it is giving a regular input so you could style it how you want